# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page using spring and hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /person.jsp at line

    </c:if>
    <tr> <td> <form:label path="name">
                 <spring:message text="Name"/>
             </form:label></td>

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:471)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please improve the problem description! See [ask] and share a [mcve]! Thank you!

Comment: Check your jsp page for missing tags or incorrect syntax. (that's what the error says basically)

Comment: could you post jsp code please?^